# Publish jms message to WMQ mule

Tags: mule

I want to publish jms message to Websphere MQ,so I made the configuration changes in my mule configuration file as

targetClient="JMS_COMPLIANT" specification="1.1"/>

But still I am not able to publush jms message I am getting an error like

Root Exception stack trace:
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCMQ0004: The value '-999999999' was not valid for the property 'targetClient'.
The value of the property 'targetClient' was none of the valid values for this property.
Set the property to a valid value.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

I cannot use Jms connector here as per my project requirement,
can anybody help me in publishing JMS message to WMQ without using Jms connector

Below is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd">
<wmq:connector name="MyQueue" hostName="XXX" port="XXX" transportType="CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ" channel="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN" queueManager="DevQueueManager1" password="XXX" username="XXX" targetClient="JMS_COMPLIANT"/>
<jms:object-to-jmsmessage-transformer name="Object_to_JMSMessage" doc:name="Object to JMSMessage"/>
<flow name="mqconnectorflowFlow" doc:name="mqconnectorflowFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\Mule-Documents\MyTasks\WMQ\In" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="DevQueue"  connector-ref="MyQueue" doc:name="WMQ" targetClient="JMS_COMPLIANT"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: I have to solve this Issue urgently,can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Add your config to the post. That will help in providing a quick answer.

Comment: added the detailed configuration,please let me know the solution of this Issue

Comment: any answer or suggestion on this please